# SQL | select statement | Temp Column data type

Tags: sql, select, types

I am doing a calculation in select statement and displaying the result in a temp column. The ouput is a number with several places after the decimal. I need it to be fixed to upto 2 decimal places.

Many Thanks!

Comment: What is the question? How to round / truncate? Or are you looking for a data type?

Comment: Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your question is unclear, this what I assume you want:

```
SELECT ColumnName, ROUND(ColumnName,2) AS Rounded
 FROM TableName;
```

Comment: Sorry about being  unclear. here is my query (Select SUM_AMT/NUM as AVG_AMT
from TableName; I need AVG_AMT to be upto 2 decimal places only.

Comment: I got it; Select Round(SUM_AMT/NUM, 2) as AVG_AMT from TableName;    Thank You AnzDevil92